# How to Access Microsoft band sensors in Ionic Framework Android App

Tags: ionic-framework, microsoft-band

I know microsoft has the SDK out for the band, and I can use Xamarin to write the app. Sadly im not good at xamarin. Is there a way to access the band sensors using Cordova, Ionic, AngularJS?

Answer (score 1):

A Javascript API for the Microsoft Band does not exist. You could make a feature request for a Javascript API to the Band SDK in a future version of the SDK at the UserVoice page for the Band: https://microsofthealth.uservoice.com/forums/283636-microsoft-health-and-microsoft-band